# If $x=\sqrt2+\sqrt3+\sqrt6$ is a root of $x^4+ax^3+bx^2+cx+d = 0$ the what is the value of $|a+b+c+d|$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots

> If $x=\sqrt2+\sqrt3+\sqrt6$ is a root of $x^4+ax^3+bx^2+cx+d = 0$ then what is the value of $|a+b+c+d|$?

My first thought was to substitute $x$ in equation. But  that way is very lengthy.  I looked for any other way to approach it.  But I could not find a reasonable approach. Any suggestions??

Comment: Hint: Square $x-2= \sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$. Rearrange & Square again.

Comment: Since you have one root, you can find the rest 3. Your first root is on x axis. Since you have 3 more roots, you divide the plane into 4 parts, I.e. you know that your angle will be $\pi/2$. After finding remaining 3 roots you can set up a system of 4 equations and find the 4 unknowns.

Comment: @ElenKhachatryan can $3$ more roots be convex roots? And I want to understand what "you divide the plane into $4$ parts$ mean.

Comment: Donald. If I do as you say we get a polynomial of degree 4. But there are many polynomials with same root. How can we be sure that we get that specific polynomial that is asked in question

Comment: I mean the complex plane. And yah 3 more complex roots making it a total of 4 complex roots. Dividing the plane is a very crude way of saying that each of your roots will be found on the dividing line that passes through the origin and makes the angle $\theta$ with the x plane.

Comment: Roll back the edit ? ... OK ... Square $x-\sqrt{6}=\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$. Collect all the root six terms on one side & square again.

Comment: In this format, the problem has infinitely many solutions. Because you have no conditions (control) on $a,b,c,d$ and therefore they can be any four real numbers (depending on other three roots). If you require them to be rationals or integers, find the minimal polynomial as suggested by others and evaluate it at $x=1.$

Comment: Should we be assuming that all the coefficients are rational numbers here? If so then this is a classic sort of question from the material leading up towards Galois theory (And there is in fact only one polynomial that works). If not then there are many polynomials with that root and different values of $|a+b+c+d|$.

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit  Ok I get it,it gives correct result but I have one doubt.there are many other possibilities for other three zeros and still have one zero is $\sqrt2+\sqrt3+\sqrt6$ but doing your method yields only one case.

Answer (score 2):

If you can use linear algebra, try this.

Write $x\cdot1$, $x\cdot \sqrt2$, $x\cdot \sqrt3$, $x\cdot \sqrt6$ as integer linear combinations of $1,\sqrt2,\sqrt3,\sqrt6$. Write these integers as columns in a matrix $A$. Find the determinant of $A-I$. This is $f(1)$, where $f$ is the characteristic polynomial of $A$, which is monic of degree $4$ and has $x$ as a root.